# AC current and the light of our house

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

We get an AC current in our house whose value changes constantly

Once it becomes positive once it becomes negative and sometimes zero. So why a light glowing in our house does not blink if there is change in voltage??

Comment: great question but have you noticed that when you rub your hands it becomes warm irrespective of the direction you rub them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the frequency (50Hz or 60 Hz)at which the AC current alternates between both directions, the blink of the bulb cannot be seen by the naked eye. Or if it is a filament bulb, then the cooling of the filament is not possible in that short duration, as in either direction there is a resistance by the filament, which heats up and glows.

Comment: It is possible to see the flicker at 50/60Hz under the right conditions, some fluorescent bulbs were known to be annoying for this.  Filaments are ok as you say.  LED is interesting and requires special circuits for dimming to avoid flicker.

Comment: I didn't know this...!